# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: scala, datetime, jodatime, databricks, runtimeexception

I work on a project where I use a library, which is very new to me, although I was using it in other projects, without any problems.

> org.joda.time.DateTime

So I work with **Scala**, and run the project as a job on **Databricks**.

> scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

The code, where the exception comes from - according to my investigation so far ^^ - is the following:

```
    var lastEndTime = config.getState("some parameters")

    val timespanStart: Long = lastEndTime // last query ending time
    var timespanEnd: Long = (System.currentTimeMillis / 1000) - (60*840) // 14 hours ago

    val start = new DateTime(timespanStart * 1000)
    val end = new DateTime(timespanEnd * 1000)

    val date = DateTime.now()
```

Where the **getState() function returns 1483228800** as *Long* type value.

**EDIT**: I use the start and end dates in filtering while building a dataframe. I compare columns (timespan type) with these values!

```
val df2= df
           .where(col("column_name").isNotNull)
           .where(col("column_name") > start &&
                  col("column_name") <= end)
```

The error I get:

> ERROR Uncaught throwable from user code: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unsupported literal type class org.joda.time.DateTime
>   2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

I am not sure I actually understand how and why this is an error, so every kind of help is more than welcome!! Thank you a lot in advance!!

Comment: Are you using Dataframe api?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using DF API, but I definitely use dataframes, and org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

Comment: In that case, edit your question and add your DF code for a better understanding

Comment: I'm not sure if that code example helps! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common problem when people start to work with Spark SQL. Spark SQL has its own [types](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types) and you need to work with them if you want to take advantage of the Dataframe API. In your example you can not compare a Dataframe column value using a Spark Sql function like "*col*" with a DateTime object directly unless you use an UDF.

If you want to make your comparison using the Spark sql functions you can take a look to [this](https://www.mungingdata.com/apache-spark/dates-times) post where you can find differences using Dates and Timestamps with Spark Dataframes.

If you (for any reason) need to use Joda you will inevitably need to build your UDF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.format.{DateTimeFormat, DateTimeFormatter}

object JodaFormater {
  val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
}

object testJoda {

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{udf, col}
  import JodaFormater._

  def your_joda_compare_udf = (start: DateTime) => (end: DateTime) => udf { str =>
    val dt: DateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(str)
    dt.isAfter(start.getMillis) && dt.isBefore(start.getMillis)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val start: DateTime = ???
    val end : DateTime = ???

    // Your dataframe with your date as StringType

    val df: DataFrame = ???
    df.where(your_joda_compare_udf(start)(end)(col("your_date")))

  }
}
```

Note that using this implementation implies some overhead(memory and GC) because the conversion from StringType to a Joda DateTime object so you should use the Spark SQL functions **whenever you can**. In some posts you can read that udfs are black boxes because Spark can not optimize their execution, but sometimes they help.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort you put in this answer, now I understand what did I try to do. I decided not to use joda, and changed the start and end to java.sql.Date type (and the current date is coming from java.time.LocalDateTime)! Now it works, so thank you a lot again!! :)