# Calculate workdays between 2 dates in Databricks

Tags: python, scala, databricks

I have 2 date parameters such as @StartDate and @EndDate, i need a Userdefinedfunction(UDF) code to calculate the number of weekdays between those 2 dates in DATABRICKS.

Can someone please help me with this code.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56850663/6802156. Here you can see how to deal with Dates using Joda to do that kind of operation.